# Shrink disk (Thick Provisioned) size of CentOS VM and reclaim disk space on ESXi host

Tags: centos, disk-usage

Our customer has VM with CentOS on ESXi host. I have to shrink the disk size of the  VM and need to reclaim that free disk space back to ESXi host. Disk type on VM is Thick provisioned.

How to do it?

Comment: The best way would be to create backup of this VM, create new VM with smaller disk assigned to it and restore backup on new VM. Anyway - you have to do a backup before you do anything with this VM

Comment: Please tell us which Linux filesystem

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Filesystem is ext4

Comment: Please tell us the mountpoint too.

Answer (score 0):

1) In vcenter record current data store
  2) on linux server - dd if=/dev/zero of=//0file bs=20971520; rm -f //0file
  3) In vcenter - migrate to another data store as Thin Provision (migrate option and check change storage only, then click on advanced button when selecting storage and using pull down that initially says to keep formate -  change to thin provisioning) 
  4) in vcenter - migrate back to original data store from step 1
  5)  On linux server set up a crontab entry to do fstrim for filesystem (on some systems can set an option in fstab to do fstrim immediately,  but I've seen posts that say it can hurt performance).